# asp.net cookie expiration always 12:00:00 AM

Tags: asp.net, cookies

No matter what I set the asp cookie expiration time as, the browser always reports the days correctly, but the time is always 12:00:00 AM. (Wednesday, January 22, 2014 12:00:00 AM)

Here is the code I am working with:

```
Dim UserNameCookie As New HttpCookie("Username")
    Response.Cookies.Add(UserNameCookie)
    UserNameCookie.Secure = True
    UserNameCookie.HttpOnly = True
    UserNameCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1)
    UserNameCookie.Value = UserName.Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime.Today` property:

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx

Try using `DateTime.Now` instead:

> An object whose value is the current local date and time.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx